# What does circle symbol between two functions means?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I have two function $f$ and $r$, such that: $y = f(x)$, $r(y) = x$. I read that it means that: $f \circ r = I_{U}$, where $x \in U, y \in U$, where $U$ is a finite set. What does $f \circ r = I_{U}$ mean? What does this circle mean and how could i read all this writing $f \circ r = I_{U}$ ?

Comment: Seems like $I_U$ is the identity map on $U$. In general $\circ$ denotes composition between functions.

Comment: It means "composition".  Thus $g\circ h(x)=g(h(x))$.

Answer (score 2):

The $\circ$ symbol corresponds to the [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). For any two functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$, the new function "$g$ composed with $f$" (denoted by $g\circ f$) is a new function defined as $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$.

In your case, you have X=Y=Z=U and $g=r$. Then, $I_U=r\circ f$ seems to be the identity function on $U$.